# Issue in writing values from dictionary to csv row

Tags: python, csv

I'm having an issue writing parsed content from a web crawler to a CSV file.

```
csvfile = open('names.csv', 'a+')
fieldnames = ['news_url','news_title','news_author','date_pub','date_up','news_desc']
writer = csv.DictWriter(csvfile, fieldnames=fieldnames)    
writer.writeheader()
data_list = {
    'news_url': news_url,
    'news_title': news_title,
    'news_author': news_author,
    'date_pub': date_pub,
    'date_up': date_up,
    'news_desc': news_desc,
}
if '' not in data_list.values():
    writer.writerow(data_list)
```

I get a format like the following file 
https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/my-contents/names.csv

Comment: 1) please paste a sample of your file and 2) what is the issue?

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] in the question itself. Give an example input with an example output. It is rude to expect people to download off-site resources. Put a little effort into crafting a well-formed, on-topic question and you will receive a much better response to your query.

Answer (score 0):

You have not included what your data looks like. I assume you have a list of data values.

From the code you have, `data_list` is only a single row. As such it should be written using a single call to `writerow()`, there is no need to iterate over the `data_list` dictionary you have created:

```
import csv

fieldnames = ['news_url', 'news_title', 'news_author', 'date_pub', 'date_up', 'news_desc']

with open('names.csv', 'w', newline='') as f_output:
    csv_output = csv.DictWriter(f_output, fieldnames=fieldnames)
    csv_output.writeheader()

    data = [
        ['url1', 'title1', 'author1', '1/1/2018', '2/1/2018', 'blah1'],
        ['url2', 'title2', 'author2', '1/1/2018', '2/1/2018', 'blah2'],
        ['url3', 'title3', 'author3', '1/1/2018', '2/1/2018', 'blah3'],
        ['url4', 'title4', 'author4', '1/1/2018', '2/1/2018', 'blah4']]

    for news_url, news_title, news_author, date_pub, date_up, news_desc in data:
        data_list = {
            'news_url': news_url,
            'news_title': news_title,
            'news_author': news_author,
            'date_pub': date_pub,
            'date_up': date_up,
            'news_desc': news_desc}

        csv_output.writerow(data_list)
```

Which would create `names.csv` containing:

```
news_url,news_title,news_author,date_pub,date_up,news_desc
url1,title1,author1,1/1/2018,2/1/2018,blah1
url2,title2,author2,1/1/2018,2/1/2018,blah2
url3,title3,author3,1/1/2018,2/1/2018,blah3
url4,title4,author4,1/1/2018,2/1/2018,blah4
```

---

If your data really is similar to `data` above, then using a `DictWriter` is a bit overkill as your data would already be a list of elements in the correct order and size. If this is the case, the following approach would be much easier:

```
import csv

fieldnames = ['news_url', 'news_title', 'news_author', 'date_pub', 'date_up', 'news_desc']

with open('names.csv', 'w', newline='') as f_output:
    csv_output = csv.writer(f_output)
    csv_output.writerow(fieldnames)

    data = [
        ['url1', 'title1', 'author1', '1/1/2018', '2/1/2018', 'blah1'],
        ['url2', 'title2', 'author2', '1/1/2018', '2/1/2018', 'blah2'],
        ['url3', 'title3', 'author3', '1/1/2018', '2/1/2018', 'blah3'],
        ['url4', 'title4', 'author4', '1/1/2018', '2/1/2018', 'blah4']]

    csv_output.writerows(data)
```

This would produce the same output. They both assume you are using Python 3.x.

Comment: The script is scraping a website and getting each entry in a variable and before writing it to a file I create a dictionary of all variables and write the dictionary as an entry one at a time

Comment: You will need to add more to your script so I can recreate your problem. At the moment it does not work.